# Subfigure labeling adding too much space between figure and caption for single figure

Tags: spacing, graphics, numbering

I am using the suggestions provided in related SO questions and the problem is that it is adding too much space below the figure (a flow-chart) and the sub-captions.  I would like the space to be removed (i.e., single space between them).

Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure*}[b!] 
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Static_analysis_diagrams_3.eps}
  \subfloat[]{\hspace{.22\textwidth}}
  \subfloat[]{\hspace{.28\textwidth}}
  \subfloat[]{\hspace{.23\textwidth}}
  \subfloat[]{\hspace{.29\textwidth}}
  \caption{\label{fig:flow_chart} Test caption.}
\end{figure*}
```

Which produces this amount of spacing:

[image]

In this style of publication, the spacing is a bit of an eyesore. So I would like it to be right up against the figure.
I've tried `\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-15pt}` and `\hspace{-1cm}` adjusting.

Comment: Could you please add a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce teh output you get?

Comment: Try setting \abovecaptionskip=0pt and/or \belowcaptionskip=0pt.  (For some reason, packages like to switch \abovecaptionskip and \belowcaptionskip, so you can never be sure which is actually above or below.)